# How to expose port in Ubuntu Firewall

Tags: azure, port, firewall, azure-hdinsight

I have created Edge node inside a HDI Cluster in Microsoft Azure.

I have started Java server in the edge node with port 13080 and it started successfully. But I am not able view it in the browser. Its doesn't get loaded.

I am using Linux OS. I believe Firewall is blocking the Port to be visible.I believe this is due to the fact that I have not opened port 13080 to public. Any idea on how the port should be exposed would be of great help.

Comment: Is the port open on the firewall? Did you create an inbound security rule on the network security group?

Comment: Could you give me the result `netstat -ant|grep 13080`?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, I did create an inbound ruke on the national security group for port 13080. But I am not able to open the port on the firewall                                                                                                               `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=13080/tcp --permanent
sudo: firewall-cmd: command not found`

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I don't see any results for the command `netstat -ant|grep 13080` since the port is not yet open

Comment: Yes, you should check your service firstly.

Comment: @Rbj What is your Linux version `firewall-cmd` only supports RHEL.

Comment: Hi, if you start your service, could you access it?

Comment: @Rbj  Does it work?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT The linux version of the HDI cluster where my edge node is running is ` lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial`    If `firewall-cmd` only supports RHEL how am I supposed to open the port in my edge node. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139736/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-rpj).

Comment: For test, you could try to disable firewall `sudo ufw disable`

Comment: Just some suggestion,. First per my experience, for network security, normally to set `iptables` to limit some specified ips or ports, please check whether enabled `iptables` on Ubuntu for HDInsight. The second suggestion is try to check the NSG for HDInsight cluster nodes, whether there was not an inbound rule for your port `13080` on Azure portal. Any update, please feel free to let me know.